# Node MongoDB execution order

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using `collection.insert` then in the callback `collection.findAndModify`

About 10% of the time `collection.findAndModify` fails to find the document I just inserted, even though it's being executed after the insert callback. Why is this possible? How do I deal with that?

[image]

I insert it, then try to modify it, but it's not there, then try to modify it again and it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the second command in the callback as the `insert` is asynchronous. If you are using the `mongodb native driver` for node,

```
collection.insert(document, function(err, records){
     //call collection.findAndModify here

});
```

Check [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html)

Comment: Yes, I am using npm `mongodb`, and this is exactly what I'm doing, `I'm using collection.insert then in the callback collection.findAndModify` I guess I'll need to create a simple way to replicate the issue

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar Sorry I overlooked that part in your question. All hell will break loose if this is true, something must be wrong.

Comment: Yes, please add as simple a code snippet as you can find to recreate the issue.